# Installing Cocoapods broke previously installed packages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am making a swift project and I decided to install Cocoapods in order to access functionality I did no have access to before. I had the firebase-ios-sdk packages installed prior to adding Cocoapods to the project. I am opening the project using the xcworkspace created by Cocoapods, and the packages that were working previously are now not working. The main error I am getting is: Missing package product "name". I am getting this error for all of the packages installed with the firebase-ios-sdk. I have attached an image of an example of just one of the errors. Can anyone assist with this issue? I am on Xcode 13.4.1, M1 Air with 12.4 Monterey, and cocoapods 1.11.3 installed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Better, can you attach error log and your `Podfile` content.

Comment: @JayachandraA Do you know how to properly uninstall dependencies from Swift package manager? There is an issue when I try to reinstall firebase-ios-sdk because it is being updated from the same place twice. Here is an image: https://imgur.com/a/FAZmwS9